# Q library (javascript) - handling q.reject() in a promise with Q.all()

Tags: javascript, q

I'm building a blog site w/Express, and using Q for the first time, and I was hoping to tap into the knowledge of veteran Q users.

I'm making one request to my DB to load post data, and another request that hits the Instagram API (unless it's already cached) and returns some json. So I have something like:

`Q.all([blogPromise, instagramPromise]).then(good, bad);`

The issue/question I'm running into is that say my request fails in my `instagramPromise` and I call `deferred.reject()`, my `bad` function is called. However, I still want to load the page with the blog post data if my `blogPromise` resolves, but it seems I'm not getting any arguments when my `bad` function is called (e.g. I don't get the blogPromise data that was successfully fetched).

Given this, it seems my only option is to not call `deferred.reject()` when I have an error, and instead call `deferred.resolve()` with something like `deferred.resolve({error: true})` which I can then use in my `good` function to handle what gets passed to my view.

So my question is, does this sound right? Is this not a misuse of Q using `resolve` when in fact I'm running into an error and should be using `reject`? Or am I missing something with Q that would allow a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your promise to resolve when both `blogPromise` and `instagramPromise` either resolves or rejects, you need to use [`allSettled` method](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination). Here is an example from the documentation:

```
Q.allSettled([blogPromise, instagramPromise])
.then(function (results) {
    var loaded = results.filter(function (result) {
        return result.state === "fulfilled";
    });
    good(loaded);
});
```

Inside of `allSettled`'s then callback you can filter successfully loaded results and pass them to the `good` function. Or handle failed results somehow with `bad` one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
Q.all([
    blogPromise,
    instagramPromise.catch(function() { return {error: true}; })
]).then(good, bad);
```

It's similar to the approach you mention, with the difference that the error suppression is done in the place where it's used, rather than in the place where the error originates.